# Is there a PHP HTML tag library?

Tags: php, html, tags

Is there a PHP HTML tag library for doing server-side HTML tags? Java and ASP.NET have these but those are compiled langs vs. scripted. For example, in ASP.NET, you define a textbox control using this:

```
<asp:TextBox />
```

And you can reference it server-side and assign properties, etc. Wasn't sure if such capability exists for PHP. Thanks.

Comment: An absolutely horrid (or wonderful, depending on how much you like XML) answer is XSLT.

Comment: Googling yielded [Phable](http://phable.sourceforge.net/introduction.php). Never used it, dont know if it's any good. That's why it's just a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's not a built-in way to do it but template systems can add similar functionality. I personally use [Smarty](http://smarty.net). It's not quite the same but it's similar.

For example, check boxes:

```
{ html_checkboxes name="foo" }
```

Or a date picker

```
{ html_select_date time=$some_unix_timestamp }
```

Also easy to extend it with plug-ins

Comment: Can Smarty be used in Joomla 1.5?

Comment: I don't use Joomla so I honestly don't know. A quick google suggests maybe but I didn't find anything concrete.

Answer (score 3):

Some frameworks have some implementations of this approach, e.g. [form helper](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html) in CodeIgniter or [view helpers](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html) in Zend framework.